# Отладка шаблонизатора Blade в Laravel-проектах

Tags: laravel, blade, laravel-8

Делаю Laravel-8 проект c иерархическим наследованием шаблонов, и раз-через-раз вместо расширения шаблона вижу вывод в браузере директиву @extends('что-то-там'). Бывает доходит до вообще странного! Не работает, возвращаю содержимое к первоначальному (работающему) виду - **и все равно не работает**! Запуск вот таких команд все равно не решает проблему:

```
@echo off
cd laravel
php artisan optimize
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan route:cache
php artisan view:clear
php artisan config:cache
cd ..
```

Зато решается иногда каким-то немыслимым способом, типа "вставить в начало шаблона пустую строку". Сами понимаете - это "метод научного тыка" и не наш вариант. Уже голову сломал, может при сохранении в файлах нужно отключать BOM, или изменить CRLF на LF...

Не хочу грузить конкретной проблемой, а хочу найти способ самостоятельного поиска источников ошибки в работе шаблонизатора `Blade`.

**Вопрос**

Какие способы отладки отладки работы шаблонизатора Blade существуют? Ну или хотя бы как определить источник неправильной работы директивы `@extends`?

P.S. Debugbar (`barryvdh/laravel-debugbar`) никаких ошибок не видит, а честно выводит  порядок использованных вьюх. Естественно, при ошибке, количество вьюх уменьшается - пропадают те, которые не включились директивой `@extends`.

Comment: Может быть это поможет: https://packagist.org/packages/bdelespierre/laravel-blade-linter. Я попробовал, синтаксическую ошибку в шаблоне нашел. Хотя при рендере шаблона эта ошибка также показалась в браузере. Если не показывается - ставьте конфиг app.debug в true

Comment: Спасибо, попробую! debug у меня включен в .env, тут все в порядке. Кстати ... уверен, что нашел причину "нестабильной ошибки" :-) Скорее всего, что в Blade-шаблонах использовал "сырые" HTML-комментарии. Все заменил Blade-комментариями - уже несколько часов полет нормальный)